# Android Facebook SDK(API v2.0) : How to perform calls to API v1.0?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I work on an Android App with the last version of Facebook SDK, so I know that it works with
API v2.0. The App sends the access token to a server and then receives user details.

The server works with Facebook API v1.0, so the user id that I get from the server is not valid for the request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[user id from server]/picture?width=100&height=100
```

**when the user id is mine (the logged in user)**. The response is

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) No node specified",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

**It does work for other users.**(friends)

As suggested, I added a call to

```
Settings.setPlatformCompatibilityEnabled(true)
```

but it doesn't change anything.

What can I do to force the current SDK to work with API v1.0 ?
Is it possible ?

The web App was up before 4/30/2014, so my Android App should be able to work with API v1.0, right ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you created your app after 4/30/2014 you can't.

Comment: I haven't seen it in the Facebook docs.A web app was created earlier, would it be possible to perform API calls 'manually'(for the web app) ?

Comment: If your app was active before 4/30/2014 you can call API v1.0

Answer (score 0):

If you created your FB app before 4/30/2014, you can call

```
Settings.setPlatformCompatibilityEnabled(true);
```

to force using v1.0 of the Graph API.

Note that this will only work until 4/30/2015, so I would recommend migrating your server side to start using v2.0 of Graph API.

Comment: Should that method call be enough ? Seems like it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It should if you do it at the start of your app.